# Get number of rows in SQL-Server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am fairly new to SQL-Server and PHP, but I'm trying to get the total number of rows in my table with PHP.

This is the code I am using, it connects just fine, however it won't print the number of rows:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"petitionlist");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     ?>
        <b>Error: </b>Could not connect to the server database.
     <?php
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$tsql = "Select Count(*) from SignatureTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     ?>
     <b>Error: </b>
     <?php
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    ?>
    <b>Result:</b><br />
    <?php
print_r(sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt));

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

If I execute the "Select Count(*) from SignatureTable" command on the SQL Server Studio it returns the correct number.  So It's not my server, it's my code.

Comment: What *does* that code print? What happens if you give that result field an alias (which is definitely a good idea to make addressing that field easier)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your call to

```
print_r(sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt));
```

might be wrong. At least looking at the documentation in regards to how the call is made, indicates that there might be an error there.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php

You might want to try using fetch instead of fetch-object. I would suggest following the example.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php

Answer (score 2):

Check it:

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php

"`sqlsrv_num_rows()` — Retrieves the number of rows in a result set"

Like:

```
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt);
echo 'numRows: ',$row_count;
```

Comment: Are you really suggesting to do a `SELECT *` just to see the row count?