# Count number of rows within to find an amount of rows to specific values

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I know there have been lots of questions about this but I need some specific help, I'm new to sql and php, so sorry for bad coding and poor indenting. What I am trying to do is count the number of rows to a specific column then when I find out how many have this id from this column then I would like it to send this number back to the php page. ATM I am using a like query I don't want this effected.

My layout is 3 pages the index the part choices and the part location, the user inputs a part number into the index page which is then searched against the database which then displays the parts that match or are like the users input on the part choices page. then you click on the part you want and then it takes you to the locations page and showing the closest locations for this part.

What I am trying to do is when the user puts in the part number a query runs and searches the database counting the number of rows that have or are like the input, then outputs the parts like it usually does, but what i want to happen is if there is only one row with that part number i want it to say row = 1 so i can then run an if statement using this value. i have looked into different code and cant quiet find what I'm looking for these are the examples I have found and have tryied to modify for what I need. but i have had no luck.

```
$query = "SELECT (column) FROM table WHERE column = value";
2.$results = mysql_query($query);
3.$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
4.echo $rows ;
```

seperate code below

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

i would like the code or query to be within the php that i have, any ideas would be great or examples sorry about poor english many thanks

my code for my page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
        document.getElementById("start").click(); // Simulates button click
        document.submitForm.submit(); // Submits the form without the button
    }




</script>
</head>
<body>      
            <?php
            try {
                    $serverName = "188.64.188.89";
                    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"tdStoreLocator", "UID"=>"odbcAdmin", "PWD"=>"Midnight1Midnight1");
                    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
                    if( $conn === false ) 
                    {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT TOP 10 [company]
                            ,[partnum]
                            ,[description]
                            FROM [tdStoreLocator].[odbcadmin].[Part]
                            WHERE Part.partnum LIKE ? or Part.description LIKE ?";          
                    /* Set parameter values. */
                    $params = array(  "%" . str_replace(" ","%",$_POST["part"] ). "%", "%" . str_replace(" ","%",$_POST["part"] ) . "%");

                    $i = 0;
                    $x = true;
                    /*echo print_r($params, true);*/
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );


                    if( $stmt === false) 
                    {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                    }

                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                    {
                    if($x == true)
                    {               
                        echo"<form id=\"submitForm\" action=\"locations.php\" method=\"post\">";
                            echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"part\" id=\"3\" value=\"".$row['partnum']."\">";
                            echo"<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"lon1\" id=\"1\" value=\"".$_POST["lon1"]."\">";
                            echo"<input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"lat1\" id=\"2\" value=\"".$_POST["lat1"]."\">";
                            echo"<button id=\"start\" type=\"submit\">";
                            echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                                    echo $row['partnum']."<br/>";
                            echo "</div>";  
                                    echo"<img style=\"width:50%;\"; src=\"productimages/".$row['partnum'].".jpg\" alt=\"Save icon\" onError=\"this.src='productimages/noimage.jpg'\"/>";
                            echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                                    echo $row['description'];
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo"</button>";
                        echo"</form>";
                    }   
                    $i++;
                    }
                    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
                }   
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                    }

                    if($i < 1) 
                    { 
                        echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;\">"; 
                        echo "No results found, Please check your spelling of the part number or description.";
                        echo "</div>";
                    } 

                    if($i == 1 ) { 


                    echo"<img onload=\"setTimeout(submit(),00001);\" src=\"index.jpg\"  onError=\"this.src='productimages/noimage.jpg'\"/>";


                    }

            ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have looked at that post but he was having problems with displaying the results i am having problems with the query that searches through the database to look for the specific amount of rows that have the part number that is like or the exact same as the users input @RC

Comment: I think you missed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12336863/180100) talking about `sqlsrv_num_rows`

Comment: how would i use this to get the results i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use `count` in query.

```
$query = "SELECT count(column) FROM table WHERE column = value";
```

Answer (score 1):

following step count search value in mysql table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldName = fieldvalue";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
echo $rows ;
```

Comment: as i typed above in my question i have tryied this code before and could not get this to work this is the same code as i put in the question above. and also within my question i also mentioned i am not using a mysql database i am using a microsoft sql database

Comment: sorry my I thought its mysql.